# errors while installing php for apache

Tags: php, apache

i'm installing php so that i can use it with the apache software and i've followed the guide here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-php-on-apache-in-windows/
but when i do the command : `httpd -t`
i get the error :

> httpd: Syntax error on line 538 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load \xe2\x80\x9cC:\php\php8apache2_4.dll\xe2\x80\x9d into server: The specified module could not be found.

i know there is some people with similar problem but i didn't find a solution that suit the problem.
i'm using Apache 2.4 VS16 and php 8.1.6 VS16 x64 Thread Safe

Comment: It would probably be easier to install WAMPServer or XAMPP as you get Apache/MySQL/mariaDB/PHP/phpMyAdmin etc etc all for one simple install

Comment: The path `\xe2\x80\x9cC:\\php\\php8apache2_4.dll\xe2\x80\x9d`  seems to be all kinds of messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the error message. Search for the bits that look weird.

See [this page](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal):

> ```
> U+201C    “   \xe2\x80\x9c    LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
> U+201D    ”   \xe2\x80\x9d    RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
> ```

You need to use **regular** quote marks (i.e. `"` which is `U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK {double quote}`) around strings.

Don't copy/paste code from blogs that use software designed for English and not code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the line so instead of having:

```
LoadModule "php_module C:\Apache24\PHP-8.2.0\php8apache2_4.dll"
```

you should have:-

```
LoadModule php_module C:\Apache24\PHP-8.2.0\php8apache2_4.dll
```